# How can I get user id for likes of my page?

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk, facebook-fql

I'm developing for a Facebook page with Graph API, and would like to know how to get the user IDs of users who like my Page, even though I can get picture and name of those fans using [the social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

I've tried the following methods with no luck:

Two graph methods:

- `graph.facebook.com/page_id/members/` doesn't work
- `graph.facebook.com/page_id/members/user_id` works, but one by one

Two FQL queries:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id="124618122608487" and uid=me() 
-- works, but one by one

SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id="124618122608487" 
-- doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5):

Facebook won't tell you who likes your page, just an aggregate total number.

> Note: for privacy reasons it is not possible to query for all users
>   who like a Page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Comment: Facebook documentation says you can't.

Comment: I understand the privacy reasons, but I'm still feeling strange because I can get some name of fans via social plugins.

Comment: In the fact, I can watch the name of fans, but I can't get the id of fans. This difference might be important as Facebook privacy???

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to log in to the page you may like to know about the signed request:
here is my example code:

```
<?php

list($a, $b) = explode('.', $_REQUEST["signed_request"], 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($b, '-_', '+/')), true);
print_r($data);

?>
```

Comment: OP is asking about how to retrieve a list, checking the signed_request will not do that, nor will it return the user ID unless the user has authorised the app

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible by default. But you can use Facebook Connect to get a user to be logged and then you can get info about him.