# How does one generate UIDs of people who have liked a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-page

There is a way to generate a list of UIDs of people who have liked a particular page and it's not necessary that you are an admin of the page. One has to enter the facebook page https://www.facebook.com/pages/(PageID) and generate a list of UIDs of people who have liked that page. Could you please help me with the easiest way to get this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible for an admin, much less a non-admin [How can I get user id for likes of my page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238841/how-can-i-get-user-id-for-likes-of-my-page)

Comment: Thanks Brad! There's a person i know who does it but won't tell me how. I'm guessing it's an application that he's created for himself. Anyhow, thanks for responding. Cheers!